# unable to create exact path

Tags: swift, swift3, cashapelayer

I want to create image view like this.
   [image]

With Bezier path, the code i tried is

```
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: myImage.frame.size.width - 10 , y: myImage.frame.size.height))

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: myImage.frame.size.width - 20 , y: 20))

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: myImage.frame.size.width, y: 20))

    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: myImage.frame.size.width/2, y: myImage.frame.size.height/2), radius: myImage.frame.size.width/2, startAngle:-CGFloat(M_PI_2), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2), clockwise: false)

   //        

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: myImage.frame.size.width/2, y: myImage.frame.size.height))

    path.close()

    UIColor.red.setFill()

    path.stroke()

    path.reversing()
```

Answer (score 0):

**code**

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 153.5, y: 137.5))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 63.5, y: 196.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 130.5, y: 137.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 63.5, y: 120.37))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 63.5, y: 310.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 63.5, y: 260.99), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 63.5, y: 218.5))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 88.5, y: 352.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 63.5, y: 333.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 73.5, y: 347.5))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 218.5, y: 360.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 137.23, y: 368.74), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 218.5, y: 360.5))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 240.5, y: 309.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 218.5, y: 360.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 240.5, y: 337))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 222.5, y: 249.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 240.5, y: 282), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 222.5, y: 249.5))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 240.5, y: 196.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 222.5, y: 249.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 240.5, y: 224.5))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 218.5, y: 137.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 240.5, y: 168.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 218.5, y: 137.5))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 153.5, y: 137.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 218.5, y: 137.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 201.5, y: 137.5))
bezierPath.close()
UIColor.gray.setFill()
bezierPath.fill()
UIColor.black.setStroke()
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1
bezierPath.stroke()
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: Not really useful as it is not using the `imageView` frame

Comment: mask your image view with the path created.